# Calling a native function from managed code

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I have a managed C++/CLI project which must use some native code. A simplified version of the native header file would be:

```
struct structA
{
   // Some variables...
};
struct structB
{
   // Some similar variables...
   void convertTo(structA& dest);
};
```

This header is included in the managed code. The managed code has:

```
structA sA;
structB sB;
// Load data into sB...
sB.convertTo(sA);
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and compiling the managed code with `/clr`. This of course generates a linker error ([LNK2028](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235590.aspx)), as the implicit calling conventions differ. However I have been unable to use `extern "C"` declarations to solve this (or perhaps I'm using them wrong). I have tried several of the solutions provided to similar questions here, to no avail.

How do I correctly call the unmanaged function from the managed code? What declaration or wrapper is required here?

Comment: I am compiling with `/clr`, actually...

Comment: Ok, sorry, that's what the error help page seems to imply

Comment: C-style declarations in a .h file must be wrapped with `#pragma managed` so that the compiler knows that the functions are not managed code.  Or the function declarations must specify the calling convention explicitly, always the best thing to do.  Use the __stdcall or __cdecl attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was not a managed-unmanaged clash issue. I simply forgot to declare the used function as exported, i.e.,

```
__declspec(dllexport) void convertTo(structA& dest);
```

The second, more general linker error ([LNK2019](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx)) for an unreferenced function was what I should have been paying attention to. It is strange that a managed-unmanaged clash error ([LNK2028](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235590.aspx)) was thrown as well, since this is a more specialized error (which also threw me off track). As far as I know, this error should only have applied was I to use `/clr:pure`, as was suggested in the comments as well.